# How can SELECT COUNT(*) different from count of all records in the table?

Tags: sql, select, sap-ase

So I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME (
    COLUMN_1   char(12)    NOT NULL,
    COLUMN_2   char(2)     NOT NULL,
    COLUMN_3   char(1)     NOT NULL,
    COLUMN_4   int         NOT NULL,
    COLUMN_5   char(2)     NOT NULL,
    COLUMN_6   money       NOT NULL,
    COLUMN_7   smallint    NOT NULL,
    COLUMN_8   varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    COLUMN_9   smallint    NOT NULL,
    COLUMN_10  datetime    NOT NULL
    Primary Key (COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2, COLUMN_3)
)
```

`SELECT COUNT(*)` returns a different value than `SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*)`. How can this be possible?

I also tried

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT
        COLUMN_1,
        COLUMN_2,
        COLUMN_3,
        COLUMN_4,
        COLUMN_5,
        COLUMN_6,
        COLUMN_7,
        COLUMN_8,
        COLUMN_9,
        COLUMN_10
     FROM TABLE_NAME
    ) TMP
```

which returned the same count as the distinct query.

I can't see how with a primary key and all fields being NOT NULL, there can be a different total count than the count of unique records.

BTW, this is on Sybase ASE 15.

The discrepancy is a hundred or so records out of a half million. I'm also seeing this problem in several other tables, but chose just one for the example.

### Edit

I should mention for the sake of completeness that I discovered this problem when writing a simple job to completely copy this table to a remote database. My application was recording a certain number of read/write operations, but failed QA because the number of records in the source database differed from the number of records in the target database. Both values were obtained via `COUNT(*)`; the count returned from the target (Oracle 10g) was the same as the number of read/write operations recorded by my app. As all fields on the source table are defined NOT NULL and a primary key is defined, I was at a loss to explain how my application was losing a tiny number of records.

This is when I started using the alternate queries listed above, both of which agreed with my apps read/write count, as well as the `COUNT(*)` value returned from the target. In other words, the only value that did not match was the `COUNT(*)` on the source database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In most databases that support it, `count(*)` doesn't actually retrieve all records and count them -- instead it fetches some metadata field that just tracks the number of rows (or approximate number of rows) presently stored in the table.  On the other hand, when you do something that requires working with actual data, the dbms is going to fetch the rows anyway, and it will count them as you would expect it to.

Of course, it's reasonable to expect that, regardless of how it's implemented, the result of `count(*)` would be the same as more a complex but equivalent query.  That would suggest then, that (maybe) your table's metadata is corrupted somehow. (I'd say this one is a good bet -- I'm not familiar with sybase specifically, but most dbms have a way to force rebuild the table metrics... that might be worth a try here).

Another possible explanation is that the database's internal table row counter is actually not designed to be 100% accurate. (this second possibility is pure educated speculation... I don't actually know whether this is true of Sybase's row counter or not, but it might be worth further investigation).

Comment: Thanks. I actually discovered that running my queries against fields in the table forced a refresh of the metadata, so now the select count(*) is returning the same number as everything else. The possibility of some sort of stale cached count had occurred to me, but as I'd never encountered a problem like this, it seemed like I was grasping at straws.

Comment: @PerformanceDBA, As I said, I don't know much about Sybase - it's entirely possible that my answer is incorrect for that system.  However, I know for a fact, that some common databases *do* work exactly the way I described.  [Check the docs for MySQL's count(*) for an example](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count).

Comment: I know you are well-intentioned, mate.  This is a Sybase question (maybe I should have said "your post is incorrect for Sybase").  I know MySQL is different, I have explained how they come to be different in the Responses section in my answer.  Just following the SO FAQ, and *above all* identifying incorrect answers.

Answer (score 2):

#### This is a Sybase ASE Answer for a Sybase ASE Question

It applies to any Standard SQL Compliant DBMS; it **does not** apply to others.

The answer you have chosen is not correct.

1. `COUNT()` is an ISO/IEC/ANSI Standard SQL expression.  It is required to **physically count the rows**, which means it will be slow on a large table.  It is required to **not** use the internal memory resident tables or catalogue tables ("metadata").  This is a run-time value, so if the table is active, it will keep changing for every execution

- What you place within the brackets is very important.
- `COUNT(*)` returns the number of rows including nulls
- `COUNT(column)` returns the number of rows where `column` is Not Null
- Yes, the placement of `DISTINCT`is also important.  This forces the use of a work table.  If you need to count a column that is not Unique, then you do not have a choice; but for unique columns, there is no need to use `DISTINCT`
- `DISTINCT` applies to a column or an expression derived from a column;
  `COUNT (DISTINCT *)`
  is meaningless ("distinct all columns"), and ASE 15 has a substantially improved parser, which catches such things (previous version woul dhave returned a less accurate error message).
- the rows actually read will depend on your ISOLATION LEVEL (the correct count will be returned for the level specified) and the current activity on the database
- the cleanest method, that avoids the weird results you are getting, is to use
  `COUNT(PK_column)`
- (Since this is a CW) Never use any form of `COUNT()` for an existence check, as it physically counts the rows.  Always use `IF EXISTS` with the correct `WHERE` clause, because it will use the index only.

2. If you need an accurate count but do not want to read all the rows, there is a function to read catalogue table `systabstats`, which has a count of rows in each table.  This returns instantaneously, regardless of table size.  The currency of those values depends on how your server is configured for performance, flushing, checkpointing, etc.  `systabstats` is updated from the memory-resident tables by two commands: UPDATE STATISTICS and "flush stats".  Try this:

   ```
   EXEC sp_flushstats
   SELECT ROW_COUNT (DB_ID(), OBJECT_ID("table_name") )
   ```

#### Response to Comments

**This Section is Not Relevant to Sybase**

1. I have provided a clean explanation re your problem, and the subject, without explaining why the other two answers are incorrect, or why your second query returns unpredictable results.
2. Here is the [**Sybase ASE 15.0 Reference/Building Blocks Manual**](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.blocks/blocks.pdf), `COUNT()` is on page 121.  Note that icyrock has misquoted it, and both of you have mis-interpreted it, inadvertently of course.  Your starting point was confusion, lack of distinction re `*` and `DISTINCT`, hence my attempt at a clear answer.
3. I made this a Community Wiki, therefore my answer is complete re the subject, normalised, so that it can stand alone as a complete answer to any question re `COUNT()`.
4. In response to comments, for those people who have not heard, SQL is a Standard language, invented and progressed by IBM in the 1970's and accepted as a Standard in the 1980's by:

- [**International Standards Organisation**](http://www.iso.org/iso/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=45498),
- [**International Electrotechnical Commission**](http://www.xcdsql.org/Summary%20of%20SQL.html) and [**(Book Format)**](http://webstore.iec.ch/servlet/GetPreview?id=40405&path=info_isoiec9579%7Bed2.0%7Den.pdf),
- and copied by [**American National Standards Institute**](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/%7Eshadow/sql/sql1992.txt) (free publication thanks to Digital Equipment Corp) somewhat later.
- **None** of the Open Source or freeware "SQL" comply with the Standard.  They provide some components (language structures, facilities, commands) of the Standard.  And of those they provide, they seldom provide the Standard Requirement (eg. ACID Transaction handling; security; etc).
- The second difference is Architecture, and in the implementation of SQL as a genuine language (consistency, callable from any code segment).  A single genuine multi-threaded process with no context switching cannot be compared with a herd of hundreds of programs using Unix to do all its "multi-threading" and context switching.
- Therefore what SAP/Sybase and DB2 (rigid regarding Standards) do, and to a lesser extent what MS ("flexible" about implementations) do, because (a) they are Standard-Compliant (without arguing the small variations), and (b) they have a genuine Server Architecture, is light years away from the MySQLs and the PostgreSQLs of the world.  The result is the hardware requirement that is 100 times that of an architected Server.  You get what you pay for.
- Oracle has a special place because it is commercial and common, however it is not SQL compliant (in language or in ACID Transactions, and it stretches the definitions).  Further, it has no architecture, which places it in the freeware category.
- Then there is **non-Standard** or anti-Standard category.
  MySQL/MyISAM provides `COUNT()` in a manner that is specifically **against** the Standard (this is plainly evident from the [MySQL Manual link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) provided by Lee; good for non-transactional apps).
  MySQL/InnoDB & BDB provide `COUNT()` in the Standard-compliant manner.
- PostgreSQL is the worst, despite the heavy marketing.  In addition to not being SQL compliant, it has no concept of ACID Transactions, and the "SQL" is not implemented as a language (Rule 4 in Codd's Twelve Rules).  Unfortunately with each major release, as it implements some increment of SQL, you have to re-write your code.
- All Standard-SQL vendors provide a large array of Extensions to the Standard

5. The `NOT NULL` in the table definition cannot be immediately trusted, because the table may well have had null columns in it before the current definition was implemented.  Nevertheless, Sybase and DB2 will count throws physical, as per requirement for Standard compliance.  You can prove with with a series of counts:`SELECT COUNT(column_1) from table_name`, and then compare the counts.
6. The second query will further confuse you, yes, because when the inner table is created, and populated, the count will be accurate.  Since you created it with an expectation, it fulfilled your expectation.  But that does not prove anything about that original table.

Comment: Correct info, but not related to the actual question (see table schema and alternative query @Ickster posted)

Comment: @John.  Don't worry about the "correct info"  The table schema is not relevant (a) I posted a CW; (b) OP could have set the columns NOT NULL after populating the rows with nulls.  Please explain how "it is not related" or what the alt query has to do with it (I have not explained why the alt query gets its weird results separately).  I trust you gave the two incorrect answers -1 as well.

Comment: You have made a number of interesting assertions here - and you sound quite well informed -- it would be great if you would provide some links (eg. to the relevant parts of spec) that would support the things you've said.

Comment: I understand that the standard would specify that count() actually return a physical count of the rows, but I know that the table in question was static and I was getting a result from count() that differed from the actual number of records I was able to read. Further, flushing the stats did in fact cause count() to return the correct value. Whatever the standard says, it appears Sybase ASE 15 is doing something different.

Comment: @PerformanceDBA: what links?  I don't see a single link anywhere in your answer.  Are you saying I should read your answer then go click on ickyrock's links for a reference?  And what about the "ISO/IEC/ANSI SQL standard" that you mentioned - is that contained in the Sybase manual too?  And why do you say I've "mis-interpreted" the Sybase manual?  Pretty difficult since I have (a) not referenced the Sybase manual in any way, and (b) specifically stated (three times now) that I'm not very familiar with Sybase specifically.

Comment: @Lee. Chill.  I have updated my post, please read again. Where have I said that you mis-represented the Sybase manual ?!?!?

Comment: @PerformanceDBA: I am chill.  You deleted the comment, addressed to me, in which you said that ickyrock and I had both misinterpreted the sybase documentation.  Thank you for adding a link to your answer - I think it improves the answer substantially (which is why I suggested it in the first place).  I'd still like to see a link to the relevant part of the "SQL Specification" that you mentioned in part 1 -- if you have a reference handy.  cheers.

Comment: @Lee. I swear, I stated (and still state, see my Response (2) ) it was icyrock and Ickster who mis-interpreted (not mis-represented) the manuals; check my activity and see for yourself. I still agree, you did not say anything about manuals.  I cleaned up the comments to reduce noise (eg. I have now posted the content in my answer).  People: **I have added to my post again**, more links

Comment: @Lee. Re Relevant part of SQL Spec. These Specs, like good textbooks, are not available as links on the web, free.  They have commercial value, you have to buy them, the 1st two links I provide are for purchasing directly from the standards bodies.  The 3rd link provides a free txt copy of an obsolete version, but you can peruse it.  Go for it.  Note that, like law books, each spec is integral under many different specification categories; so the full spec covering `COUNT()` has to be drawn from say, 10 single specs.

Comment: @Ickster. 1) Updated my post. 2) The testing itself, would have caused stats to be renewed (not flushed). Is it possible that the table you thought was static **might not** have been ? 3) Ok, so, **after** you flushed stats, what did ASE 15 do that was incorrect ? 4) I don't care about points but other SO readers will be mislead by the ticked answer: now that you know the chosen answer is incorrect, you can "unchoose" it and choose a different answer.

Comment: @PerformanceDBA , ok. There're a few reasons I downvoted your answer:
 - There're too many irrelevant info, i.e. discussion on COUNT's behaviour for null value is irrelevant because the table schema already defines all fields to be not null.
 - The part about 'systabstats', it's a very bad idea to write vendor specific queries. This query might not be replaceable in another dbms, even if it is, there's no guarantee that the behaviour will be the same.

continued below......

Comment: - Lee's answer already points out the most likely cause for this problem, the alternative query (forcing a working table) shows there's a disjoint between database stats and actual row nums. Screaming that being the incorrect answer without anything to back it up warrants some down voting to avoid confusion

Comment: @John.  1) read again, it is a vendor specific question. 2) Schema issue is explained, null are relevant to the question 3) Specifically what has not bee "backed up" 4) Let me get this right.  You are a technical professional downvoting the correct answer without reading my answer fully ?

Comment: Well, I'm still not convinced that the chosen answer is incorrect. Maybe I'm missing it, but I haven't seen an explanation of how the value of COUNT(*) could be incorrect, which (see the edit to the OP) it pretty clearly seems to have been.

Comment: @Ickster.  Could you please execute step (5) in my Answer, for every column, and provide the results. `COUNT()` can be trusted, you need to understand the flavours.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, judging from this:

- http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-as/asg1250e/sqlug/@Generic__BookTextView/8007;pt=7889

you should use `select count(distinct *)`. I'd expect `select distinct count(*)` to always return 1, as it says "give me the distinct rows, each of which is a `count(*)`", so there's always going to be one row, while `select count(distinct *)` gives you a count of distinct rows.

FWIW, the above seems to be for v12.5 (though I don't see any differences), here are the 15.0 docs:

- http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.blocks/html/blocks/blocks128.htm

It explicitly says the following:

> count(*) finds the number of rows. count(*) does not take any arguments, and **cannot be used with distinct**. All rows are counted, regardless of the presence of null values.

You can use `select count(distinct column_1)` or so, but not `select count(distinct *)`.

Comment: To what version do those docs refer? SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT *) FROM . . . gave a syntax error.

Comment: @PerformanceDBA Thanks, it actually was SO's quoting system that "removed" it, as `*` is a special character. I updated for the future.